# Box-Shadow on a Single Table Column with CSS

Tags: css, html-table

I'd like to have the left most column of my table have a box-shadow, similar to what is seen [in this demo](https://colorlib.com/etc/tb/Table_Fixed_Column/index.html) (scroll the table for it to appear), minus the box-shadow disappearing. I've tried using two **tbody** elements and floating the first column to the left, but to no avail.

My two concerns are that a) the box-shadow is only visible on the right side of the column and not outside of the table, and b) that if the text in the first column has to wrap, the remaining columns are still aligned with the first (if possible). Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: if you inspect the element you will see that the shadow is applied to a DIV and not a table ... they are not using a single table but 2 table add appling a trick for a fixed part

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you inspect the code of that demo you will see that the table is actually two tables put together and the box shadow is being applied to a div wrapping the first table. Box shadow won't work on tbody tags as far as I know, maybe you need to add display: block?